# How can I delete row from sql database where 2 different data equals to something?

Tags: php, android, database

I have a textview when I click it it deletes one row from table if my user's id equals to id in table. But now I want to delete the row where two different data from user equals to data in a table.
Here is my php code:

```
public function deleteUser($email, $name){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE email = ? AND name = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $name);
            if($stmt->execute())
                return true; 
            return false; 
        }


$app->delete('/deleteuser/{email}{name}', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args){
    $email = $args['email'];
    $name = $args['name'];
    $db = new DbOperations; 
    $response_data = array();
    if($db->deleteUser($email, $name)){
        $response_data['error'] = false; 
        $response_data['message'] = 'User has been deleted';    
    }else{
        $response_data['error'] = true; 
        $response_data['message'] = 'Plase try again later';
    }
    $response->write(json_encode($response_data));
    return $response
    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    ->withStatus(200);
});
```

I have already tested it by using postman and it works very well but when I implement this code into android it crashes. Here is my API class:

```
@DELETE("deleteuser/{email}{name}")
    Call<DefaultResponse> deleteUser(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("name") String name

    );
```

And this is the activity where I delete user:

```
User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(MySettingsActivity.this).getUser();

                        Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().deleteUser(user.getEmail(),user.getName());
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {

                                if (!response.body().isErr()){

//                                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(MySettingsActivity.this).clear();
//                                    Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(MySettingsActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
//                                    deleteIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//                                    startActivity(deleteIntent);
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(MySettingsActivity.this, response.body().getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                            }
                        });
```

When I deleted the user only by one data for example id it worked normally but when I want to delete it by two data it crashes? Please help me where I have a mistkake?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand what exactly happening, please read about the debugging. With debugging you could execute line by line your php code. You will see each variable. It will be so easy to find out where is your logic problem.

P.S. Not recommend, also you could write some `var_dump`, and see what you exactly received from client.

Comment: know where is my problem.

Comment: Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().deleteUser(user.getEmail(),user.getName());

Comment: here in this code when I want to delete user by two strings

Comment: when I do this operation with one string everything is ok

Comment: thans for recommending to debug. I have found my problem. It was in my API I used FIELD instead of PATH.